# Validate text format when render page

Tags: input-formats

Im making an exportation process (from SQL Server to MySql) and in the text_format column insert NULL values, currently the page is rendering the pure html (plain text) instead of render the html correctly in the browser.

Somebody know how to force the output text_format to be filtered_html to my specific content type?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the inserts are taking place on field tables (e.g. `field_data_body`, `field_data_field_MACHINE_NAME`), you shouldn't insert NULL into the *_format columns. Rather, you should be inserting the machine name of your desired filter format (e.g. `filtered_html` for Filtered HTML or `full_html` for Full HTML). See the `filter_format` table for all available machine names for your installation.